# Jupyter / Tornado "DeprecationWarning: `should_run_async` will not call `transform_cell` automatically in the future"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, tornado

I have a very simple iPython notebook `my_nb.ipynb` with two simple cells

```
from mcmc import Tree
```

```
a = Tree()
print(a)
```

This code used to run without problems, but recently has stopped functioning when I run it in Jupyter (and, of course, the code in `mcmc.py` has not changed). When I run this code with `ipython my_nb.ipynb` the script runs fine and finishes without error. However, when I open the notebook in Jupyter, the first cell runs fine but the second stalls and never finishes, and the console shows the following error (or warning, really):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 542, in execute_request
    reply_content = yield gen.maybe_future(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 287, in do_execute
    and should_run_async(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2954, in should_run_async
    warnings.warn(
DeprecationWarning: `should_run_async` will not call `transform_cell` automatically in the future. Please pass the result to `transformed_cell` argument and any exception that happen during thetransform in `preprocessing_exc_tuple` in IPython 7.17 and above.
```

Perhaps even more puzzling, if I put all the code in a single cell in the notebook, then the whole code finishes without error both in the command line **and** in Jupyter.

I have checked [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413807/deprecation-warning-from-jupyter-should-run-async-will-not-call-transform-c) but my ipykernel is already up to date. In fact, I think all relevant libraries are all at their most current versions:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.18.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.6
jupyter lab      : 2.2.7
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3
tornado          : 6.0.4-2
terminado        : 0.8.3-1
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By any chance, do you happen to have 'warnings.filterwarnings("error")' or a similar line somewhere in your code?

I just bumped into the same situation just today and have finally traced the problem to this line of code, which was used in my custom package. Once I comment this line out in my code, this Jupyter hanging problem disappeared.

During troubleshooting, I saw this question, so I thought I should write this information down just in case somebody else may benefit from this.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem! Thank you so much!! Now, I guess that this shouldn't happen anyway, right?

Comment: Glad it helped. Sure, I wish this error doesn't happen. It wasn't happening before I created a new conda env. There was a reason why I placed that line previously. I just submitted an issue at https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5757, and hope it gets addressed.